# How use jQuery String variable in html body

Tags: jquery, html

I found some problem in using jQuery String variable in html body

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var string = "test";
      $('#string').val(string);
});
```

in html body :

```
<a id="y"></a> 
<!-- if I use <input> instead <a> I got the result, 
but I want a simple text not input field.  -->
```

Thanks

Comment: `.val()` is used to set the element `value` attribute. There is no `value` attribute on `<a>` element. Try `$('#y').html(string);`

Comment: (.text or .html) both are correct, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ...

```
$('#y').text(string);
```

... `val` changes the value; and only works with elements that have a value type.  The `text` function will change the displayed text of an element that doesn't have a value.

```
<a id="y"></a>
```

Comment: Yes, was just adjusting that.